# SlideToggle nav menu disappearing too fast

Tags: jquery, css

i have this slidetoggle function:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function (){
      jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
      });
    });
  });
```

which works fine if i remove "400, function()", when i click the menu-trigger, the menu appears. but with it added, the menu appears then disappears too quickly, i want it to display like a standard navigation dropdown.

here is my CSS for media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.menu-trigger{ /*displays menu-trigger as a block but only when max-width is
hit */
display: block;
color: white;
background-color: #5978cf;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
font-size: 83%;
cursor: pointer;
}

div.nav-menu{ /*hides nav-menu when under 480px */
display: none;
}

.div.nav-expanded{
display: block;
}

div.nav-menu ul li {
float: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d5dce4;
}

div.nav-menu ul li:last-child{
border-bottom: none;
}
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{
content: "";
display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
clear:both;
}
.clearfix{
*zoom:1;
}
```

i think its to do with the "400" but i have seen articles and videos of this process and they all seem to work, so don't understand why mine doesn't.

Comment: `400` is the number of milliseconds the animation takes to complete. If you want to slow it down, make the number larger

Comment: i have set the figure to 1500, so the menu is slower displaying... but i guess once it hits 1500, the menu disappears.. whereas some examples i have seen show the menu at 400, and the menu displays for a while after its fully loaded (presuming it stays displayed until another click somewhere), any ideas how i do that?

Comment: instead of the jquery i posted above, i have changed it to:
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
         $('.nav-menu').slideToggle("fast");
          });
         });

but if i add:

$(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', ''); AFTER
         $('.nav-menu').slideToggle("fast" {

when the screen is bigger than media queries i get the nav menu back but my mobile nav doesnt work? i click but nothing happens.

Comment: Why are you setting the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the display setting which jQuerys slideToggle() sets, that why the menu gets hidden. Remove that from the code and it should work fine.

The next problem you face is your css. Consider a 'mobile first' approach like in this example to avoid those kinds of problems.

In this example on a window wider than 480px the "MENU WRAPPER" gets shown while the "Button" is hidden on a window narrower, the button shows up and toggles the menu.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function (){
    jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle('fast', function(){
      jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-trigger{ 
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #5978cf;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 83%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-menu{
  display: none;
  background: green;
  padding:6px;
}
.nav-menu.nav-expanded{
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .menu-trigger{
    display:none;
  }
  .nav-menu{
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-trigger">BUTTON</div>
<div class="nav-menu">MENU WRAPPER</div>
```